# Каким образом я могу проверить таблицу SQLite на существование нужной мне записи?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

У меня есть форма регистрации. Нужно, чтобы если пользователь вводил имя, существующее в базе данных, ему выдавалась ошибка.

Догадываюсь, что это очень просто, но сам до этого додуматься не могу.

Comment: В цикле просматриваете вашу таблицу до тех пор, пока в каком-то поле не найдете нужное значение. Нашли значение - вывели ошибку и вышли из цикла.

Comment: Сделай поле уникальным и лови состояние запроса

Comment: Спасибо, как я мог не увидеть способ сделать это через cursor. Всё было еще проще, чем я думал.

Comment: А эта бд не поддерживает SQL ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Надо использовать [UNIQUE constraint](http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-unique-constraint/).
Решение задачи через `cursor` не оптимально, так как:

- Перебор всех записей для проверки наличия такой записи потребует времени; более того, при увеличении количества записей это время будет расти - либо линейно O(N). Для поддержки `UNIQUE constraint` SQLite создаст индексе, будет делать эту проверку за вас сама, причем за время O(log(N)).
- Пока на таблице нет `UNIQUE constraint` нет никакой гарантии, что какой-либо другой код, в котором еще нет этой проверки, не вставит дубликат в таблицу.

Comment: "Если вы попытаетесь вставить новый контакт с тем же адресом электронной почты, вы получите сообщение об ошибке." Я так понимаю, я получу его в логах. А каким образом мне отследить состояние запроса и вывести его пользователю?

Comment: Вы получите исключение (exception) в вашем коде, которое вы должны обработать. В рамках обработки этого исключения вы можете показать информацию об ошибке пользователю.